# C singly linked list throwing errors

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a singly linked list in C, but I keep getting this error:

***Error in './output.o/': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x09dd008 ***

I'm pretty new to C and thought my implementation was pretty good, but I can't seem to figure out where this problem is coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>
list llInit(){
    list llist;
    llist.head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    llist.tail = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    llist.curr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    return llist;
}

int llSize(list *myList){
    int count = 0;
    node *next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if((*myList).head!=NULL){
        next = (*myList).head;
        while((*next).next!=NULL){
            count++;
            next = (*next).next;
        }
    }
    free(next);
    return count;
}

int llAddToFront(list *myList, char *toStore){
    if(toStore!=NULL){
        node *new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*new).string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        (*new).next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*new).string = strdup(toStore);
        if((*myList).head!=NULL){
            (*new).next = (*myList).head;
            if((*myList).head==(*myList).curr){
                (*myList).curr = new;
            }
            (*myList).head = new;
        }else{
            (*myList).head = new;
            (*myList).curr = new;
            (*myList).tail = new;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int llDeleteFirst(list *myList){
    if(llSize(myList)){
        if((*myList).curr==(*myList).head){
            (*myList).curr = (*myList).head->next;
        }
        (*myList).head = (*myList).head->next;
        free((*myList).head);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int llAddToBack(list *myList, char *toStore){
    if(toStore!=NULL){
        node *new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*new).string = strdup(toStore);
        (*new).next = NULL;
        if((*myList).tail!=NULL){
            (*(*myList).tail).next = new;
            (*myList).tail = new;
        }else{
            (*myList).tail = new;
            (*myList).head = new;
            (*myList).curr = new;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int llInsertAfterCurr(list *myList, char *string){
    if(string!=NULL){
        node *new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*new).string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        (*new).next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*new).string = string;
        if((*myList).curr==NULL){
            (*myList).head = new;
            (*myList).curr = new;
            (*myList).tail = new;
        }else{
            (*new).next = (*(*myList).curr).next;
            (*(*myList).curr).next = new;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int llDeleteAfterCurr(list *myList){
    if(llSize(myList)&&(*myList).tail!=(*myList).curr){
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp = (*(*(*myList).curr).next).next;
        free((*(*myList).curr).next);
        (*(*myList).curr).next = temp;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void llClear(list *myList){
    while(llSize(myList)){
        llDeleteFirst(myList);
    }
    (*myList).head = NULL;
    (*myList).tail = NULL;
    (*myList).curr = NULL;
}

int llNext(list *myList){
    if(llSize(myList)&&(*myList).curr!=(*myList).tail){
        (*myList).curr = (*(*myList).curr).next;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int llRewind(list *myList){
    if(llSize(myList)){
        (*myList).curr = (*myList).head;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int llIterate(list *myList, fun f){
    if(llSize(myList)){
        llRewind(myList);
        while((*myList).curr!=(*myList).tail){
            f((*(*myList).curr).string);
            llNext(myList);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the simple test I'm using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(){
    list myList = llInit();
    llAddToFront(&myList,"To my friends ");
    llAddToBack(&myList,"Hello");
    llInsertAfterCurr(&myList, "I say ");
    /* iterate list front to back */
    node *aNode = myList.head;
    while(aNode!=NULL) {
        printf("%s",aNode->string);
        aNode = aNode->next;
    }
    printf("\nClearing List\n");
    llClear(&myList);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0) `node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));` malloc'd then assign `temp =  pointer;`, `temp` was rewrited. this is memory leak. temp as temporary working pointer defined just `node *temp = NULL;`(or `node *temp;`). don't need `free(temp);`

Comment: What are `list` and `node`? As an observation, I don't understand why `llSize()` which returns the list length needs to allocate and free memory, and not declare a local struct to follow a pointer chain - if at all.

Comment: No gentle way to say this: This isn't Java or C#. You don't allocate unless you need to *create* something. Ex: `malloc(sizeof(node))` has no business being in `llSize`. `(*new).next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node))` has no business being in `llAddToFront` or `llInsertAfterCurr`. And `node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node))` absolutely positively has no business being in `llDeleteAfterCurr`. I strongly advise you review both C pointers and any of a thousand online examples of linked lists that *work*.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but too much for a comment. I don't know your `struct` declarations, but an iteration to find the number of items in a linked list is quite simple, requiring no casts at all.

```
int llSize(list *myList){
    int count = 0;
    while (myList) {
        count++;
        myList = myList->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Note: One thing that *is* clear in the OP's code; `list` and `node` are distinct types. `list` has `node*` members `head`, `tail`, and `cur`, while `node` has members `char *string` and `node *next`. It isn't much to work with, but its something.

Comment: @WhozCraig I wondered about that but no detail provided. Why are two types needed?